# WF4 WCF Correlation and MessageContract not working

Tags: wcf, workflow, workflow-foundation-4, correlation

I have a WF4 WCF service that i am trying to get correlation to work using Content based through the soap message.

I am getting the following error message:

```
<Message>A correlation query yielded an empty result set. Please ensure correlation queries for the endpoint are correctly configured.</Message>
           <StackTrace><![CDATA[at System.ServiceModel.Activities.Dispatcher.CorrelationKeyCalculator.Calculator`1.CalculateKeys(T target, Message messageToReadHeaders, InstanceKey& instanceKey, ICollection`1& additionalKeys)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activities.Dispatcher.ControlOperationInvoker.GetInstanceKeys(OperationContext operationContext, InstanceKey& instanceKey, ICollection`1& additionalKeys)
at System.ServiceModel.Activities.Dispatcher.ControlOperationInvoker.ControlOperationAsyncResult.EnsureInstanceId()
at System.ServiceModel.Activities.Dispatcher.ControlOperationInvoker.ControlOperationAsyncResult.Process()
at System.ServiceModel.Activities.Dispatcher.ControlOperationInvoker.ControlOperationAsyncResult..ctor(ControlOperationInvoker invoker, Object[] inputs, IInvokeReceivedNotification notification, TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Activities.Dispatcher.ControlOperationInvoker.InvokeBegin(Object instance, Object[] inputs, IInvokeReceivedNotification notification, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)]]></StackTrace>
```

here is my class

```
[MessageContract(IsWrapped = false)]
public class ClaimObj
{
    [MessageHeader]
    public string CorrelationId { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember]
    public string InstanceId { get; set; }
}
```

here is my xaml with the namespaces changed for proprietary reasons

```
<Activity mc:Ignorable="sap" x:Class="Project.WorkFlow.Activities.Activity4" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="654,676" mva:VisualBasic.Settings="Assembly references and imported namespaces for internal implementation" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities" xmlns:av="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:mv="clr-namespace:Microsoft.VisualBasic;assembly=System" xmlns:mva="clr-namespace:Microsoft.VisualBasic.Activities;assembly=System.Activities" xmlns:p="http://ns.ns2.com/" xmlns:p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/servicemodel" xmlns:qm="clr-namespace:Project.MessageWrappers;assembly=Project.MessageWrappers" xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:s1="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System" xmlns:s2="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.Xml" xmlns:s3="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.Core" xmlns:sa="clr-namespace:System.Activities;assembly=System.Activities" xmlns:sad="clr-namespace:System.Activities.Debugger;assembly=System.Activities" xmlns:sap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities/presentation" xmlns:scg="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=System" xmlns:scg1="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=System.ServiceModel" xmlns:scg2="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=System.Core" xmlns:scg3="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:sd="clr-namespace:System.Data;assembly=System.Data" xmlns:sl="clr-namespace:System.Linq;assembly=System.Core" xmlns:ssa="clr-namespace:System.ServiceModel.Activities;assembly=System.ServiceModel.Activities" xmlns:ssx="clr-namespace:System.ServiceModel.XamlIntegration;assembly=System.ServiceModel" xmlns:st="clr-namespace:System.Text;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<Flowchart sad:XamlDebuggerXmlReader.FileName="D:\Activity4.xaml" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="614,636">
<Flowchart.Variables>
  <Variable x:TypeArguments="qm:ClaimObj" Name="RequestObj" />
  <Variable x:TypeArguments="p1:CorrelationHandle" Name="handle" />
</Flowchart.Variables>
<sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
  <scg3:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
    <x:Boolean x:Key="IsExpanded">False</x:Boolean>
    <av:Point x:Key="ShapeLocation">270,2.5</av:Point>
    <av:Size x:Key="ShapeSize">60,75</av:Size>
    <av:PointCollection x:Key="ConnectorLocation">300,77.5 300,107.5 290,107.5 290,115</av:PointCollection>
  </scg3:Dictionary>
</sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
<Flowchart.StartNode>
  <FlowStep x:Name="__ReferenceID1">
    <sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
      <scg3:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
        <av:Point x:Key="ShapeLocation">162.5,115</av:Point>
        <av:Size x:Key="ShapeSize">255,90</av:Size>
        <av:PointCollection x:Key="ConnectorLocation">290,205 290,235</av:PointCollection>
      </scg3:Dictionary>
    </sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
    <p1:Receive x:Name="__ReferenceID0" CanCreateInstance="True" CorrelatesWith="[handle]" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="255,90" OperationName="Process" ServiceContractName="p:IActivity4Service">
      <p1:Receive.CorrelatesOn>
        <p1:XPathMessageQuery x:Key="key1">
          <p1:XPathMessageQuery.Namespaces>
            <ssx:XPathMessageContextMarkup>
              <x:String x:Key="xg0">http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Project.MessageWrappers</x:String>
            </ssx:XPathMessageContextMarkup>
          </p1:XPathMessageQuery.Namespaces>sm:header()/tempuri:CorrelationId</p1:XPathMessageQuery>
      </p1:Receive.CorrelatesOn>
      <p1:ReceiveMessageContent DeclaredMessageType="qm:ClaimObj">
        <OutArgument x:TypeArguments="qm:ClaimObj">[RequestObj]</OutArgument>
      </p1:ReceiveMessageContent>
    </p1:Receive>
    <FlowStep.Next>
      <FlowStep x:Name="__ReferenceID2">
        <sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
          <scg3:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
            <av:Point x:Key="ShapeLocation">162.5,235</av:Point>
            <av:Size x:Key="ShapeSize">255,90</av:Size>
          </scg3:Dictionary>
        </sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
        <p1:SendReply Request="{x:Reference __ReferenceID0}" DisplayName="SendReplyToReceive" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="255,90">
          <p1:SendMessageContent DeclaredMessageType="qm:ClaimObj">
            <InArgument x:TypeArguments="qm:ClaimObj">[RequestObj]</InArgument>
          </p1:SendMessageContent>
        </p1:SendReply>
      </FlowStep>
    </FlowStep.Next>
  </FlowStep>
</Flowchart.StartNode>
<x:Reference>__ReferenceID1</x:Reference>
<x:Reference>__ReferenceID2</x:Reference>
```

I know the issue is with my xpath for the correlation. I have tried many different ideas and the only one that works is 11445 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358742.aspx), but that doesn't give me the tracking with correlation. These don't work

```
sm:body()/xg0:ClaimObj/xg0:CorrelationId    
sm:header()/tempuri:CorrelationId
sm:header()/xg0:ClaimObj/xg0:CorrelationId
sm:header()/tempuri:ClaimObj/tempuri:CorrelationId
```

I can get it to work with DataContracts just fine, but i need to use MessageContracts

UPDATE:
Here is what i really need to do:

Receive request
send a one way wcf call to Server X
(2nd receive) Server X sends back to workflow in a new wcf call with correlation id, not a reply
do some other stuff
send reply to original receive

Here is the basic workflow I am trying to get working. The issue is that the 2nd receive is not being called due to the xpath not being found.

on a side note, i get the same issue when i try to use correlationinitializer in the first receive

```
<Activity mc:Ignorable="sap" x:Class="Project.WorkFlow.Activities.Activity4" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="828,872" mva:VisualBasic.Settings="Assembly references and imported namespaces for internal implementation" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities" xmlns:av="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:mv="clr-namespace:Microsoft.VisualBasic;assembly=System" xmlns:mva="clr-namespace:Microsoft.VisualBasic.Activities;assembly=System.Activities" xmlns:p="http://ns.domain.com/" xmlns:p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/servicemodel" xmlns:qm="clr-namespace:Project.MessageWrappers;assembly=Project.MessageWrappers" xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:s1="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System" xmlns:s2="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.Xml" xmlns:s3="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.Core" xmlns:sa="clr-namespace:System.Activities;assembly=System.Activities" xmlns:sad="clr-namespace:System.Activities.Debugger;assembly=System.Activities" xmlns:sap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities/presentation" xmlns:scg="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=System" xmlns:scg1="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=System.ServiceModel" xmlns:scg2="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=System.Core" xmlns:scg3="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:sd="clr-namespace:System.Data;assembly=System.Data" xmlns:sl="clr-namespace:System.Linq;assembly=System.Core" xmlns:ssa="clr-namespace:System.ServiceModel.Activities;assembly=System.ServiceModel.Activities" xmlns:ssx="clr-namespace:System.ServiceModel.XamlIntegration;assembly=System.ServiceModel" xmlns:st="clr-namespace:System.Text;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<Flowchart sad:XamlDebuggerXmlReader.FileName="D:\Activity4.xaml" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="788,832">
<Flowchart.Variables>
  <Variable x:TypeArguments="qm:ClaimObj" Name="RequestObj" />
  <Variable x:TypeArguments="p1:CorrelationHandle" Name="handle" />
  <Variable x:TypeArguments="qm:GetClaimObj" Name="GetClaimIn" />
</Flowchart.Variables>
<sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
  <scg3:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
    <x:Boolean x:Key="IsExpanded">False</x:Boolean>
    <av:Point x:Key="ShapeLocation">270,2.5</av:Point>
    <av:Size x:Key="ShapeSize">60,75</av:Size>
    <av:PointCollection x:Key="ConnectorLocation">300,77.5 300,107.5 290,107.5 290,115</av:PointCollection>
    <x:Double x:Key="Width">773.5</x:Double>
    <x:Double x:Key="Height">796.04</x:Double>
  </scg3:Dictionary>
</sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
<Flowchart.StartNode>
  <FlowStep x:Name="__ReferenceID1">
    <sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
      <scg3:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
        <av:Point x:Key="ShapeLocation">162.5,115</av:Point>
        <av:Size x:Key="ShapeSize">255,90</av:Size>
        <av:PointCollection x:Key="ConnectorLocation">290,205 290,209 241,209 241,239</av:PointCollection>
      </scg3:Dictionary>
    </sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
    <p1:Receive x:Name="__ReferenceID0" CanCreateInstance="True" CorrelatesWith="[handle]" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="255,90" OperationName="Process" ServiceContractName="p:IActivity4Service">
      <p1:Receive.KnownTypes>
        <x:Type Type="qm:ClaimObj" />
      </p1:Receive.KnownTypes>
      <p1:ReceiveMessageContent DeclaredMessageType="qm:ClaimObj">
        <OutArgument x:TypeArguments="qm:ClaimObj">[RequestObj]</OutArgument>
      </p1:ReceiveMessageContent>
    </p1:Receive>
    <FlowStep.Next>
      <FlowStep x:Name="__ReferenceID2">
        <sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
          <scg3:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
            <av:Point x:Key="ShapeLocation">120,239</av:Point>
            <av:Size x:Key="ShapeSize">242,93</av:Size>
            <av:PointCollection x:Key="ConnectorLocation">241,332 240,332 240,355</av:PointCollection>
          </scg3:Dictionary>
        </sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
        <p1:InitializeCorrelation Correlation="[handle]" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="242,93">
          <InArgument x:TypeArguments="x:String" x:Key="key1">[RequestObj.CorrelationId]</InArgument>
        </p1:InitializeCorrelation>
        <FlowStep.Next>
          <FlowStep x:Name="__ReferenceID3">
            <sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
              <scg3:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
                <av:Point x:Key="ShapeLocation">112.5,355</av:Point>
                <av:Size x:Key="ShapeSize">255,90</av:Size>
                <av:PointCollection x:Key="ConnectorLocation">240,445 240,475 241,475 241,479</av:PointCollection>
              </scg3:Dictionary>
            </sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
            <p1:Receive CorrelatesWith="[handle]" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="255,90" OperationName="GetClaim" ServiceContractName="p:IActivity4Service">
              <p1:Receive.CorrelatesOn>
                <p1:XPathMessageQuery x:Key="key1">
                  <p1:XPathMessageQuery.Namespaces>
                    <ssx:XPathMessageContextMarkup>
                      <x:String x:Key="xg0">http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Project.MessageWrappers</x:String>
                    </ssx:XPathMessageContextMarkup>
                  </p1:XPathMessageQuery.Namespaces>sm:header()/xg0:CorrelationId</p1:XPathMessageQuery>
              </p1:Receive.CorrelatesOn>
              <p1:ReceiveMessageContent DeclaredMessageType="qm:GetClaimObj">
                <OutArgument x:TypeArguments="qm:GetClaimObj">[GetClaimIn]</OutArgument>
              </p1:ReceiveMessageContent>
            </p1:Receive>
            <FlowStep.Next>
              <FlowStep x:Name="__ReferenceID4">
                <sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
                  <scg3:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
                    <av:Point x:Key="ShapeLocation">120,479</av:Point>
                    <av:Size x:Key="ShapeSize">242,58</av:Size>
                    <av:PointCollection x:Key="ConnectorLocation">241,537 240,537 240,565</av:PointCollection>
                  </scg3:Dictionary>
                </sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
                <Assign sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="242,58">
                  <Assign.To>
                    <OutArgument x:TypeArguments="x:String">[GetClaimIn.InstanceId]</OutArgument>
                  </Assign.To>
                  <Assign.Value>
                    <InArgument x:TypeArguments="x:String">Get is called</InArgument>
                  </Assign.Value>
                </Assign>
                <FlowStep.Next>
                  <FlowStep x:Name="__ReferenceID5">
                    <sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
                      <scg3:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
                        <av:Point x:Key="ShapeLocation">112.5,565</av:Point>
                        <av:Size x:Key="ShapeSize">255,90</av:Size>
                      </scg3:Dictionary>
                    </sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
                    <p1:SendReply Request="{x:Reference __ReferenceID0}" DisplayName="SendReplyToReceive" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="255,90">
                      <p1:SendMessageContent DeclaredMessageType="qm:GetClaimObj">
                        <InArgument x:TypeArguments="qm:GetClaimObj">[GetClaimIn]</InArgument>
                      </p1:SendMessageContent>
                    </p1:SendReply>
                  </FlowStep>
                </FlowStep.Next>
              </FlowStep>
            </FlowStep.Next>
          </FlowStep>
        </FlowStep.Next>
      </FlowStep>
    </FlowStep.Next>
  </FlowStep>
</Flowchart.StartNode>
<x:Reference>__ReferenceID1</x:Reference>
<x:Reference>__ReferenceID2</x:Reference>
<x:Reference>__ReferenceID3</x:Reference>
<x:Reference>__ReferenceID4</x:Reference>
<x:Reference>__ReferenceID5</x:Reference>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am missing the CorrelationInitializers in your XAML. The CorrelationInitializers is used to create a correlation on the Receive or SendReply activity with the original request. After that the CorrelatesOn is used in subsequent Receive activities.

Comment: i got the initializer in place. i have made updates to the original post

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same problem and the article you linked to actually helped me resolve it. About 3/4 of the way down the page, there is a paragraph that reads...

> If an XPath query is configured incorrectly such that no correlation
>   data is retrieved, a fault is returned with the following message: "A
>   correlation query yielded an empty result set. Please ensure
>   correlation queries for the endpoint are correctly configured." One
>   quick way to troubleshoot this is to replace the XPath query with a
>   literal value as described in the previous section. This issue can
>   occur if you use the XPath query builder in the Add Correlation
>   Initializers or CorrelatesOn Definition dialog boxes and your workflow
>   service uses message contracts.

The dialog box always generates queries that target message body properties, even when the property you select is part of the message header. The correct query to access a header property is:

```
sm:header()/namespace:property
```

Note that the property name is not qualified by the containing object, so the following query should work for you:

```
sm:header()/tempuri:CorrelationId
```

If you'd like to change the namespace of the header property, use the `Namespace` property of the `MessageHeaderAttribute` class.